# How to create Azure Blueprint using REST API in .NET

Tags: .net, azure

I want to create Azure Blueprint through REST API. Could someone clarify me on this.
I thought we can create Blueprint using REST API like ASP.NET WEBAPI, but my assumption seems to be wrong.
I didnt find any solution to create Blueprint using REST API .Net Code.

Even in Microsoft Official Document on [Azure Blueprints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/blueprints/create-blueprint-rest-api) , they have used powershell but there is no .NET Code to create Blueprint.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/blueprints/blueprints/createorupdate?

Comment: are you looking for an SDK?

Comment: If you want to know how to create Azure Blueprint with .net SDK, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/blueprints/management?view=azure-dotnet and https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/blueprint/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Blueprint/tests

Comment: Is there any sample for creating Azure Blueprint using any Console app or WebApi in .Net

Comment: @ChandraSekhar Is it helpful for you? If it is helpful for you, could you please accept it as an answer. It may help more people who have similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to use sdk `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Blueprint` to manage Azure Blueprint in console application, please refer to the steps

1. create a service pricipal

```
az login
# it will create a service pricipal and assign a contributor rolen to the sp
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp"  --scope "/subscriptions/<subscription id>" --sdk-auth
```

[image]

2. Code

```
private static string tenantId = "<the tenantId you copy >";
        private static string clientId = "<the clientId you copy>";
        private static string clientSecret= "<the clientSecre you copy>";
private static string subscriptionId = "<the subscription id you copy>";

 static async Task Main(string[] args){
    /*
      install sdk Microsoft.Azure.Management.Blueprint and Microsoft.Identity.Client

*/
   //get token
            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                       .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
                       .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                       .Build();
            string[] scopes = { "https://management.azure.com/.default" };
            var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            TokenCredentials tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken, "Bearer");
            BlueprintManagementClient client = new BlueprintManagementClient(tokenCredentials);
            var blueprint = new BlueprintModel()
            {

                DisplayName = "Sample Blueprint from Unittest",
                TargetScope = Constants.BlueprintTargetScopes.Subscription,
                ResourceGroups = new OrdinalStringDictionary<ResourceGroupDefinition>
                {
                    { "vNicResourceGroup", new ResourceGroupDefinition{ DisplayName="virtual-network-rg", Description = "All virutal network should save under this resource group." } }
                },
                Parameters = new OrdinalStringDictionary<ParameterDefinition>
                {
                    { "vNetName", new ParameterDefinition { Type = Constants.ParameterDefinitionTypes.String, DisplayName="default vNet for this subscription.", Description = "default vNet created by this blueprint.", DefaultValue = "defaultPublicVNet" } },
                    { "defaultLocation", new ParameterDefinition { Type = Constants.ParameterDefinitionTypes.String, DisplayName="default Location", Description = "default location of resource created by this blueprint.", DefaultValue = "East US" } },
                    { "defaultCostCenter", new ParameterDefinition { Type = Constants.ParameterDefinitionTypes.String, DisplayName="default CostCenter", Description = "default CostCenter for this subscription.", DefaultValue = "Contoso/IT/PROD/123456" } }
                }

            };

            // create 
            var blueprintName = "subBPfromDotnetSDK";
            Console.WriteLine("create Blueprint");
            await client.Blueprints.CreateOrUpdateInSubscriptionAsync(subscriptionId, blueprintName, blueprint);
            //get
            var blueprintGet = await client.Blueprints.GetInSubscriptionAsync(subscriptionId, blueprintName);

            Console.WriteLine(blueprintGet.DisplayName);
}
```

[image]